# NUnit failed to load in TFS build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, nunit, tfsbuild

I’m having a "build partially succeeded" issue with this error “NUnit failed to load e:\Builds\184\CSTax\706USServices_Test\bin\Calc.Tests.dll”, but all of the unit test in this project ran and passed (all green).

Build environment

1) Using NUnit 2.6.4 and NUnit Test Adapter 2.0.0

2) TFS 2013 – upgraded from 2012

3) Visual studio 2012 and 2013 have been installed on the server

4) I did install the NUnit Test Adapter, using the Extensions and Updates in 2013 Visual Studio

5) Using build process templates from TFS 2012, even if I switch to the 2013 default build process templates I get the same error

6) I tried changing the project to copy the nunit references locally (including the test adapter), they did make it to the bin folder, but still fails

7) I used process monitor to see if I could find the failure, everything looked good, the dlls were copied from the packages folder to the bin folder and loaded.

I’m sure it has to be something in our build environment, but I do not know where to look, I need my builds to go green. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the "Calc.Tests.dll"? Is it your test project? Or an assembly which is referenced in the test project? To run NUnit test during the TFS build process, please check my reply below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is a bug in the NUnit 3.0 test adapter, I removed our E2E project off of the build server and all my builds went green. NUnit is looking into this bug.

Comment: Hi I have the same problem. By any chance you have solution for yours please? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Download the NUnit test adapter: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d . Rename the NUnitVisualStudioTestAdapter-2.0.0.vsix to NUnitVisualStudioTestAdapter-2.0.0.zip. Unzip NUnitVisualStudioTestAdapter-2.0.0.zip.
2. Check in the following dlls: nunit.core.dll, nunit.core.interfaces.dll, nunit.util.dll and NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.dll into a folder in TFS Version Control.
3. Specify the build controller's path to custom assemblies:
   [image]
   [image]
4. Then queue a build, the NUnit test methods will be run.

Also have a check on the **Enable a third-party unit framework** part of this MSDN article for the details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms253138.aspx

Comment: This is a deprecated way to run tests in the build, instead you can now just add the NUnit VSRunner nuget package to your test project.