# Exception NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException on TFS server

Tags: tfsbuild, nunit-3.0

I am getting below error in my TFS build however all test are executed successfully. I am bit confused as to why this error is occurring when all required dlls are already present in the project

Exception NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException, Exception thrown executing tests in C:\NUnitPoC\UnitTest.dll

Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a of C:\Test_CI\bin\NUnitPoC\NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll not found. Can be ignored if not a NUnit project.

Library details-

NUnit.3.5.0

NUnit3TestAdapter.3.6.0

Comment: Do you use xaml build or vNext build? In which step do you get this error? Share your detailed settings of build definition.

Comment: Can you share the detailed build logs?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT I am using XAML for TFS build configuration

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT - build log can be found at -  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwytUbWrQERESmMyS2VUTjRlalE. What is interesting is that test cases are successful but TFS build reports error - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwytUbWrQEREbnZxVDhaYmFNYjg

Comment: @Naresh What's your project type? Asp.Net Web Application or Asp.Net Core Web Application? And I cannot find the error message from the build log.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Solution contains just a single class library and Test project

Comment: @Naresh Can you check if you have NUnit2.0 version installed? A similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191374/nunit-tests-throwing-exception-only-when-run-as-part-of-tfs-msbuild-process

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether you have other versions of Nunit TestAdapter, if have, try to disable them.
2. If you use vNext build, check whether you have specified `Path to Custom Test Adapters` in VS Test step:

[image]

Comment: It's a sample project which doesn't have any other version of Nunit test adapters. I also followed all ways to mentioned in link  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2012/03/03/how-to-make-your-extension-visible-to-the-test-explorer-in-visual-studio-11/ but still get same error.