# using NUnit 2 and 3 in the same solution

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, nunit-3.0, nunit-2.5.9, nunittestadapter

I have 2 test projects in my solution. One is using NUnit version 2 (integration + SpecsFor) and another version 3.(Unit tests)

Running locally this works fine but when I execute the tests as part of a build on TFS I get an error message even though all tests passes. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191374/nunit-tests-throwing-exception-only-when-run-as-part-of-tfs-msbuild-process#35193783) this occurring because VSTestAdapter2 cant run the v3 ones.

Is it not possible to run both version 2 and 3 in the TFS build?

Comment: "I get an error message" is vague, what error message?

Comment: If install Nunit3TestAdapter package way isn't fix the issue, share a simple projects on the OneDrive.

Answer (score 1):

The NUnit3TestAdapter compatible with NUnit 2, so you can install NUnit3TestAdapter package to your NUnit test projects.

[image]

Comment: Locally yes that works(despite that it actually says "use the Nunit 2 adapter for 2.x test..." but on TFS the Nunit2 does not get discovered

Comment: What're steps of your build definition? Can you share a simple projects that can reproduce this issue on the OneDrive?