# MS Build throws NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, nunit, package

I have a NUnit 3 test project, locally it works. When it's run as a TFS build using MS TEST it throws the exception:

> Exception NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException, Exception thrown executing tests in D:\Builds\Agent2\SPX\solution\bin\project.dll

He's my exact packages.config. Everything is using 3.4.1 so I'm not sure what the issue is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NUnit.Console" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NUnit.ConsoleRunner" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NUnit.Extension.NUnitProjectLoader" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NUnit.Extension.NUnitV2Driver" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NUnit.Extension.NUnitV2ResultWriter" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NUnit.Extension.TeamCityEventListener" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NUnit.Extension.VSProjectLoader" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191374/nunit-tests-throwing-exception-only-when-run-as-part-of-tfs-msbuild-process

Comment: @FahadJameel that solved it, thank you!