# Solution contains both NUnit 2 and NUnit 3 tests, I get UnsupportedFrameworkException in the TFS Build

Tags: nuget, nunit, tfs-2015

In my solution there are several projects, some are using NUnit 2 and some are using NUnit 3.

They have the relevant test adapters and versions installed via NuGet.

When my TFS build runs, I get the error:

> Error: Exception NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException, Exception
>   thrown executing tests in
>   E:\BuildAgents\Agent1_work\9\s\Kittens_Local\Kitten\kitten\kitten\Kitten.Fluffy.Tests\bin\Debug\Kitten.Fluffy.Tests.dll

This project is using version 3 while the other tests are using version 2.

Is it possible to get both working simultaneously in TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a issue in Nunit2 adapter(*Nunit TestAdapter Nuget Packag*e). So you could not get both working simultaneously in TFS. More details please refer *Charlie*'s answer in this question: [nunit tests throwing exception only when run as part of tfs msbuild process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191374/nunit-tests-throwing-exception-only-when-run-as-part-of-tfs-msbuild-process)

> If you have both adapters installed, each one will run the tests for
>   which they are designed. **Each of them will display a message in for
>   any assembly that they do not support.** The message isn't meant to be
>   an error and we try to word it in such a way that it won't be taken as
>   such. However, we felt we have to give it just in case you expected
>   the assembly to be handled by that particular adapter. Passing it by
>   silently seems wrong.
>
> When running under the VS IDE, the message does not cause a failure in
>   the test run. It appears that running under TFS does cause a failure.
>   If memory serves, we fixed this problem for the NUnit 3 adapter but
>   **not (yet) for the NUnit 2 adapter**.

Comment: Aha! So working as intended. I guess there is no workaround, which is problematic because it fails the build. Many thanks.